# UiBinder wrongly thinks I have no addValueChangeHandler method

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I have a class Selector<T> that extends ListBox and implements HasValue<T> (and thus HasValueChangeHandlers<T>) I then have:

```
@Override
public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(ValueChangeHandler<T> handler) {
  return addHandler(handler, ValueChangeEvent.getType());
}
```

I have a subclass of Selector, MessageListBox, which adds some extra functions for Selectors of certain special objects.  I then have in one of my widgets...

```
@UiField MessageListBox<Column> filterColumnSelect;
...
@UiHandler("filterColumnSelect")
void handleSelectColumn(ChangeEvent event) {
  ((Button) add).setEnabled(filterColumnSelect.hasSelection());
}
```

And this works, but I want to change the method to actually listen to the ValueChangeEvent instead, because there are places in code where I generate one (and while I've since found how to create raw ChangeEvents, I'd rather not do that here).
So, then I change the code to be...

```
@UiField MessageListBox<Column> filterColumnSelect;
...
@UiHandler("filterColumnSelect")
void handleSelectColumn(ValueChangeEvent<Column> event) {
  ((Button) add).setEnabled(filterColumnSelect.hasSelection());
}
```

But now GWT fails to compile with:
[ERROR] Field 'filterColumnSelect' does not have an 'addValueChangeHandler' method associated.

um... yes it does, it inherits it from Selector, and all these classes are public.  what gives?

Also, as a note, I looked at ValueListBox as well, but there are features I need that it doesn't support, so that's out.

Comment: I also made my own `ValueListBox` replacement at work, so I don't have the code now. But are you able to do `filterColumnSelect.addValueChangeHandler()`? If that works, your `@UiHandler` is supposed to work too.

Comment: Yes, I could add the handler manually, but the @UiHandler refuses to work anyway.

Comment: On a hunch I figured it could be that whatever process the UiBinder uses when compiling (source code analysis or reflection, I don't know the inner workings) might just not like superclass methods.  So I tried adding an overriding method on the subclass that just delegates to the superclass.  Now it works.  So, at least I know where the issue is....

Strange that it has no problem with the ChangeHandler being on a superclass, though... :-/

Comment: glad you figured it out. I don't think I've ever run into this issue. I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 2):

This is [a known bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6091). It's been fixed already and will ship in GWT 2.6.